# SQL subquery returns more rows with more columns

Tags: php, mysql, subquery

how to solve in practice [nested responds to comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOtjs.jpg)? I have a table with columns:

- **comment_id** (*int*, primary key of comment)
- **author** (*varchar*, name of sender)
- **content** (*text*, content of message)
- **book_id** (*int*, foreign key to another table)
- **response_to** (*int*, can be *NULL*, foreign key to this table)

and I would need such array from the SQL query:

```
$result = [
  [ // First comment
     'author' => 'Michael',
     'content' => 'It's very good book!',
     'responds' => [
         ['author' => 'Martin', 'content' => 'I agree.'],
         ['author' => 'Susan', 'content' => 'Hello world!.']
     ]
  ],
  [ // Another comment
     'author' => 'Tomas',
     'content' => 'Hi everyone!',
     'responds' => [
         ['author' => 'Jane', 'content' => 'Hi.']
     ]
  ],
  ...
];
```

## First solution (very ineficient)

```
// Get all the comments of this book.
$comments = $db->query('SELECT * FROM comments WHERE book_id = ? AND response_to IS NULL', [$bookId]);

// Find all the responds to each comments. 
foreach ($comments as &$comment) {
    $comment['responds'] = $db->query('SELECT * FROM comments WHERE response_to = ?', [$comment['comment_id']]);
}
```

## Second solution (not working)

```
$db->query('SELECT t1.*,
  (SELECT * FROM comments AS t2 WHERE t2.response_to = t1.comment_id) AS responds
  FROM comments AS t1 WHERE t1.book_id = ?', [$bookId]);
```

Comment: Relational db don't return  nested  table .. but relation between table .. (alias  a select with rows composed  by columns selected)   .. if you need  this second (relational) way you can do it with join ..

Answer (score 0):

Error is because you can only select one column and at most one row using the above method.

You can use left self join instead

```
select *
from comments t1
left join comments t2
on t1.comment_id = t2.response_to
where t1.book_id = ?
```